# How to determine which my.cnf mysql is using

Tags: mysql, configuration, sockets, my.cnf

Is there a way I can figure out which my.cnf mysql is currently using?  The reason is because it's using the correct socket file to connect, but I can't figure out exactly which (if any) my.cnf it's using or trying to use so I can manually set the correct path on my local machine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have found many my.cnf files on my mac and am not sure which one to edit.

Answer (score 2):

A bit hackish:

```
$ strace mysql 2>&1  | grep 'open' | grep '.cnf'
open("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
open("/home/reto/.my.cnf", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ strace -f -e trace=open mysql 2>&1 | grep $SEARCH_STRING
```

where usually SEARCH_STRING='cnf' or SEARCH_STRING='ini'

The default extentions for the mysql configuration file are '.cnf' and '.ini' (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html)